# Can't access a nested JSON object in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

AngularJS V1.6.4

$scope.aCourse["name"] is logged to console correctly, but in the HTML code nothing is populated into the screen.

```
$scope.getCourse = function(idd){
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + btoa($cookieStore.get('username') + ':' + $cookieStore.get('password')  );
        $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/course/'+idd,

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.aCourse = response.data;
                console.log($scope.aCourse["name"]);

                window.location = "/website-take-course.html";
              }, function errorCallback(response) {
                  alert("Course data in fetching failed");
              });
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="page-section padding-top-none" ng-repeat="c in aCourse" >
            <div class="media media-grid v-middle">
              <div class="media-left">
                <span class="icon-block half bg-blue-300 text-white">1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body" >
                <h1 class="text-display-1 margin-none" >{{c.name}}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <p class="text-body-2">{{c.description}}</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: post the json you see  when you console.log   $scope.aCourse

Comment: Go look in the developer tools - console for errors, or in the network tab to see what was the returned response

Comment: Why do you iterate over an **object** (`ng-repeat="c in aCourse"`) it's wrong. instead try `{{ aCourse.name }}`

Comment: did you check the answer

Answer (score 2):

Based on your post, it lookes like  $scope.aCourse is a object, not an array.

change it as follows,

```
<div class="page-section padding-top-none" ">
    <div class="media media-grid v-middle">
        <div class="media-left">
            <span class="icon-block half bg-blue-300 text-white">1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h1 class="text-display-1 margin-none">{ aCourse.name }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <p class="text-body-2">{{aCourse.description}}</p>
</div>
```

or use something like this to iterate over object,

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in aCourse">
      {{key}} : {{value}}
  </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('filterApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.aCourse = {
      "content": "SO",
      "description": "Programmers"
    };

 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="filterApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in aCourse">
     {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is possible use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"`, when data is an object.
Fix this please

Comment: LOL @MazenMohamed you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43527039/edit) your question, not other people's answers

Comment: @OmriLuzon i should have explained it better

Comment: @Sajeetharan when I tried to use the json object included in your demo, It only works if it is defined outside the " .then " function in my "http" request, If I put it inside the " .then  " function it doesn't work.

Comment: @MazenMohamed it has nothing to do with that, check you are recieving the data inside promise

Answer (score 0):

**There could be a two situations :**

**1.** `$scope.aCourse` is an array of objects `[{},{},{}]`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.aCourse = [
      {
        "name": "alpha",
        "description" : "description1"
      },
      {
        "name": "beta",
        "description" : "description2"      
      },
      {
        "name": "gamma",
        "description" : "description3"      
      }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="page-section padding-top-none" ng-repeat="c in aCourse" >
              <div class="media-body" >
                <h1 class="text-display-1 margin-none" >{{c.name}}</h1>
              </div>
            <p class="text-body-2">{{c.description}}</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

**2.** `$scope.aCourse` is an `Object` `{......}`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.aCourse = {
        "name": "alpha",
        "description" : "description1"
      };
    console.log($scope.aCourse["name"]);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="page-section padding-top-none" ng-repeat="(key, value) in aCourse" >
              <div class="media-body" >
                <h1 class="text-display-1 margin-none" >{{value}}</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your angular code you are setting aCourse to the response data. You then access the data as an object with:

```
$scope.aCourse["name"]
```

Then in your html you are running an ng-repeat on $scope.aCourse as if it were an array of objects:

```
<div class="page-section padding-top-none" ng-repeat="c in aCourse" >
```

You would either need to make aCourse an array of objects to use your current html, or update your html and access the object in aCourse with `aCourse.name` and `aCourse.description`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seem to be the correct answer

Comment: Can anyone tell me why they down voted this? As far as I can tell I gave accurate information and solutions to the problem.